# How to include other class files when using java on the command line?

Tags: java

I have a few classes in one java package. Actually, I'm using eclipse, and compiling works just fine since eclipse takes care of it. But now that I'm using the command line, compiling does not work and the error is that I am referring to class B inside of class A, and the compiler does not recognize class B.

I have done some research, and people say to use the `-cp` flag to allow the compiler to look for the other classes file. Specifically, the command I am using is `java -cp . UDPClient.java`. This returns the same error that the other class cannot be found.

Why is this and what should I do?

Comment: Are you compiling or running java code? If compiling use the `javac` command not `java`. See here for information on the javac command: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html

Comment: So I've been just doing `java udp.java` and it executes my program, without me ever doing `javac`, so I assumed under the hood `java` was doing the compilation step and then executing. Is this the case? Or...since I was using eclipse, I did notice I already had some class files in the bin directory, so maybe that's why it worked?

Comment: I do not use eclipse so I am not sure exactly how the folder structure works, but yes, typically an IDE like eclipse will compile the java files to a build/debug folder when you run the project, and you could then run those compiled files separately with the java command. If building the code yourself you will first need to compile the code using javac on the .java files and include the .class files, then to run the code you would need to do it with a new java command on the resulting .jar file